# Selenium WebDriver - Is defining WebElement selectors as a By constant a good idea?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have refactored my java project to define the WebElement selectors as By constants.  This allows me to pass a By constant into my findElement method, without requiring an evaluation of the By selector type in the method.  Is this a good idea?  What issues am I likely to encounter if I define the By variables as public static final constants?

Following is an example:

```
public static final By LOGIN_BUTTON_SELECTOR = By
        .cssSelector("input[name='logIn']");

/**
 * click the Login button
 */
public void clickLoginButton() throws TimeoutException,
        StaleElementReferenceException {
    // click the Login button
    clickElement(LoginPage.LOGIN_BUTTON_SELECTOR);
}

/**
 * 
 * find an element
 * 
 * click the element
 * 
 */
public void clickElement(By elementSelector) throws TimeoutException,
        StaleElementReferenceException {

    WebElement webElement = null;

    // find the element by By selector type
    webElement = getElement(elementSelector);

    // click the element
    webElement.click();

}

/**
 * 
 * generic method to get a WebElement using a By selector
 * 
 */
public WebElement getElement(By elementSelector) throws TimeoutException {

    WebElement webElement = null;

    // find an element using a By selector
    getDriverWait().until(
    ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(elementSelector));
    webElement = getDriver().findElement(elementSelector);

    return webElement;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a good practice.

You can use it with PageObject, see example:

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects

Comment: thank you for your reply, my main concern is if there is a problem defining the By variable as a static final constant.

Comment: The reasons it is a good practice are that: 1. It prevents the element from being changed in the test, causing potential for bad tests, 2. It gives you a central location at the top of your test to change the selector statement for your elements if they change, and 3. It will be faster (but who really cares, it's fast enough).